# How to close context action via code in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, contextmenu, xamarin.forms

I have created an app in xamarin forms, where I have used Context Actions in a list view item template's ViewCell as :

```
          <ViewCell.ContextActions>
            <MenuItem Clicked="OnEdit"
              Text="Edit"/>
            <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete"
               Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
          </ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

While I long press on any item in the list view I get context action items in action bar, and if I do not tap on any option in context action it will not be closed in android. Is there any way so that I can close that context action bar via code in xamarin forms?

Comment: Hi, I have the same question, did you find the solution?